# MongoDB get records for specific day

Tags: php, mongodb

so I am trying to get all records that are 3 days old, but I keep on getting empty results...

```
 public function getUnansweredDiscussionsForPeriod() {

        $where = [

            'related.theme_id' => 3455537,

            'date_added' => [
                '$gte' => new MongoDate(strtotime('-3 days')),
                '$lt' => new MongoDate(strtotime('-4 days'))
            ],

            'subscribers.1' => [
                '$exists' => false
            ],

            'satisfaction_checked' => [
                '$exists' => false
            ]
        ];
        return $this->get_all($where, ['uri','user_id']);

    }
```

Basically I am saving the date as ISO date.

Also just to note 1 thing, I tried removing everything else from the function to see if for example something else was the problem but nothing happened, the results were exactly the same. ALTHO when I removed the date and left everything as it is, it worked fine

This is how I save the date inside the mongo itself

```
"date_added" : ISODate("2017-12-04T12:40:31Z")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up the fields:

```
'date_added' => [
   '$gte' => new MongoDate(strtotime('-4 days')),
   '$lt' => new MongoDate(strtotime('-3 days'))
],
```

What you wrote is basically that you're looking for a document where `date_added` is newer than 3 days ago, but also older than 4 days ago

Comment: Oh wow, I totally didnt double check that... Thanks mate, that works like a charm!